# NServiceBus: WcfIntegration sample is not working

Tags: wcf, nservicebus

I just downloaded the sample for WcfIntegration from github [Source Link](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/tree/3.3.8/Samples/WcfIntegration)

After updating MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig and TransportConfig i tried to run the application but facing this issue

> The message with Action
>   'http://tempuri.org/IWcfServiceOf_CancelOrder_ErrorCodes/Process'
>   cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch
>   at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract
>   mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a
>   binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check
>   that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding
>   (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

I am using NServiceBus 4.3.0.0
Please share if you have any idea regarding this issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the v4 sample instead, https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/tree/master/IntegrationTests/WcfIntegration